# Any way to have eslint warn me if I've not passed all the parameters to a method?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is there any way I can have ESLint give a warning/error if I invoke a function or method, without supplying all the parameters?

I know JS treats missing arguments as undefined, but it'd be very help to be warned if I have fewer than expected.

Comment: You can see the list of rules [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/), and this isn't built-in. You'll have to find or write a custom rule.

Comment: There is no such rule, as depending on your other rules, it may be impossible to determine a function's signature statically.

Comment: Adding `// @ts-check` will (in VSCode) enforce that check. In the words of Shrek: "It's getting him to shut up is the trick!"

Answer (score 4):

The [current ESLint rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/) offer no such option, and for a simple reason - depending on your other rules and your code, it may very well be impossible to statically determine whether the number of passed arguments is correct or not.
See the following simple example:

```
let foo = n => n * n;
if (someExternalCondition) {
  foo = (n, m) => n * m;
}
// What should ESLint do here?
foo(42);
```

Comment: Tell you that closures should be const. :-)

Comment: This is a fairly common fallacy of claiming that the sane thing to do can't ever be done in the general case due to wacky edge cases (that probably should never even exist in the realm of programming to begin with, imo).  `function calc(x, y) { ... }` should always be called with two arguments, and can be statically checked at every standard call site.  C has been doing this before we were born.  If you are older than C and still made this mistake, shame on you!  ;-)

Comment: @SO_fix_the_vote_sorting_bug That argument falls apart on the fact that ESLint has to support everything that's valid in the language, it can't only support projects that avoid writing code "that should never even exist".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio Code with a dummy JSDoc like `/**@param _*/` above the method or put an autogenerated JSDoc, also add `"js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true` to your settings.

With both steps you will force the IDE checker to treat the method signature as TS language and will put squiggly lines on the wrong number of parameters (More parameters than expected or less parameters than expected). Optionally use `Error Lens` extension to make the alerts a lot more visible and set eslint rules that alert `no-rest-parameters`, `no-arguments` and `no-extra-arguments`

https://github.com/jfmengels/eslint-plugin-fp/blob/master/docs/rules/no-rest-parameters.md

https://github.com/jfmengels/eslint-plugin-fp/blob/master/docs/rules/no-arguments.md

https://github.com/SonarSource/eslint-plugin-sonarjs/blob/master/docs/rules/no-extra-arguments.md